# Dismiss pop-up windows from outside application with script?

Tags: popup, dismiss

I have sort of an unorthodox question/idea. I have a hydrological modeling program that is a bit buggy. I do not have access to the source code. This modeling program runs 24/7 and periodically produces assertion errors (and sometimes runtime errors) and a resulting pop-up window. Often it produces a "Send Error Message/Don't Send" pop-up only. See attached .jpgs for examples.

These windows halt all further program execution until it is dismissed (by clicking "Ignore" "Don't Send" or "OK" respectively). The assertion errors do not appear to affect program function. From the investigating I've done on dbheap.c it is likely an issue with the modeling program deallocating memory improperly at the end of a run.

I would like the program to always continue running and producing its forecasting export products even in the event of one of these errors (which, again, appear to have no effect on program function). I would like to dismiss these pop-up windows from outside the application (via a script) so that they do not halt program execution. Does Windows have a means for monitoring and/or dismissing program generated pop-ups from outside the application?

[image: Assert Error]

[image: Send-Don't Send]

[image: Runtime Erro]

Comment: Actually this looks promising: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms940840%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple application which forces the application to do things. With Winspector/Spy++ or Winsight you can see all the objects in a windows application. You could check periodically for a popup and then click a (maybe always the first) button. Windows has a API/syscall and with it, it is possible to send a message to a window (handle) of your choice (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx).